# Display values insted of index for quintiles (R)

Tags: r, plot, statistics, quantile

Quantile displays cut-off values when called on R commandline:

```
> quantile(cnt, probs=seq(0,0.95,0.05))
 0%  5% 10% 15% 20% 25% 30% 35% 40% 45% 50% 55% 60% 65% 70% 75% 80% 85% 90% 95% 
  0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   3   4   4   5   7  11
```

However,

```
plot(quantile(cnt, probs=seq(0,0.95,0.05)))
```

displays quintile index (5,10,15,20) instead of cut-off values *on X axis*.

How do I display cut-off values for quantiles on X axis on the graph?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible exemple. for exemple with something like:      cnt <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)

Comment: The graph represent in abscissa the quantile and in ordinate the value of the quantile. What do you want more exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not all that clear, but after looking at it awhile, I think it is about getting the right scale on the x-axis. I made up some similar data.

And then I think you are getting something like this:

```
cnt <- trunc(12*runif(1000)^4)+1
plot(quantile(cnt, probs=seq(0,0.95,0.05)))
```

which yields this plot:  -  (note the 5,10,15,20 - index values on the X-axis)

[image]

But what you want is something like this:

```
cnt <- trunc(12*runif(1000)^4)+1
s <- seq(0,0.95,0.05)
plot(s,quantile(cnt, probs=s))
```

Which yields this - quantile values on the X-axis :

[image]

Comment: Is this not what you wanted?